# Remover repetições em sequência de select Oracle

Tags: query, oracle, select

Estou com uma dúvida para montar uma query no Oracle, tenho o seguinte até o momento...

```
SELECT M5.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA
     , M5.GRUPO_ESTRUTURA
     , M5.SUBGRU_ESTRUTURA
     , M5.ITEM_ESTRUTURA
     , M5.SEQ_OPERACAO
     , M5.CODIGO_ESTAGIO
  FROM MQOP_050 M5
 WHERE M5.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = 2
   AND M5.GRUPO_ESTRUTURA = '00504'
   AND M5.NUMERO_ROTEIRO = 1
 ORDER BY M5.SEQ_OPERACAO
```

Me retorna...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como necessito apenas o CODIGO_ESTAGIO, estou nisso...

```
SELECT M5.CODIGO_ESTAGIO
  FROM MQOP_050 M5
 WHERE M5.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = 2
   AND M5.GRUPO_ESTRUTURA = '00504'
   AND M5.NUMERO_ROTEIRO = 1
 ORDER BY M5.SEQ_OPERACAO
```

Retorna...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DISTINCT direto não me resolveria, pois preciso manter os estágios em ordem conforme a SEQ_OPERACAO, inclusive repetindo os códigos se os mesmos não estiverem em sequência.Como no exemplo, o que eu preciso é...

```
|CODIGO_ESTAGIO
|21
|24
|23
|24
|25
```

Alguém saberia me auxiliar neste caso?

Comment: Não é possível fazer o que você quer através do SELECT.

Comment: Pois é, acho que terei que fazer isso a nível de aplicação mesmo... Valeu @ReginaldoRigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fim, como não consegui fazer via query, joguei está parte para aplicação como um método na classe.

Ficou assim...

```
public function getEstagiosPorRoteiro($roteiro = 1) {
    $estagios = array();
    $query = " SELECT M5.CODIGO_ESTAGIO
                 FROM MQOP_050 M5
                WHERE M5.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = 2
                  AND M5.GRUPO_ESTRUTURA = '$this->grupo'
                  AND M5.NUMERO_ROTEIRO = $roteiro
                ORDER BY M5.SEQ_OPERACAO ";
    $res = db_query($query, 'array');
    if($res) {
        $estagioTemp = 0;
        foreach ($res as $estagio) {
            if($estagioTemp != $estagio) {
                array_push($estagios, $estagio);
                $estagioTemp = $estagio;
            }
        }
        return $estagios;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Retornando assim um array dos estágios...

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '21' (length=2)
      'CODIGO_ESTAGIO' => string '21' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '24' (length=2)
      'CODIGO_ESTAGIO' => string '24' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '23' (length=2)
      'CODIGO_ESTAGIO' => string '23' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => string '24' (length=2)
      'CODIGO_ESTAGIO' => string '24' (length=2)
  4 => 
    array
      0 => string '25' (length=2)
      'CODIGO_ESTAGIO' => string '25' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT M5.CODIGO_ESTAGIO
  FROM MQOP_050 M5
 WHERE M5.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA = 2
   AND M5.GRUPO_ESTRUTURA = '00504'
   AND M5.NUMERO_ROTEIRO = 1
 ORDER BY M5.CODIGO_ESTAGIO
```

Para fazer isso  utilize o **DISTINCT e  o ORDER BY**  no mesmo  campo
No caso  o **M5.CODIGO_ESTAGIO**

Comment: Olá @Marcos, na verdade não é bem isso que preciso, como descrevi acima o distinct não resolve pois o estágio 24 deve repetir, e não posso perder a ordenação.